# How To Find The Highest Value And Return The Two First Adjacent Cell Value In Excel?

Tags: excel, indexing, max, match, textjoin

I would like to have the two first value but I have two exact same highest value like my highest value is 20 and two-person have 20 so Excel return me the first person but not the second and I would like to have the second with. My formula is that :

```
French one: =INDEX(D3:D14;EQUIV(MAX(H3:H14);(H3:H14);0))
English one: =INDEX(D3:D14;MATCH(MAX(H3:H14);(H3:H14);0))
```

It returns me for example "John" and I want it to return me "John Alison" because John and Alison both have 20 as highest value
Thank you very much

Comment: Are you looking to have your result return in one cell, like "John Alison?"

Comment: Yes that's what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Excel version supports the newer [textjoin](/questions/tagged/textjoin) function use this array formula.

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(32), TRUE, IF(H3:H14=MAX(H3:H14), D3:D14, ""))
```

If your Excel version does not support the newer [textjoin](/questions/tagged/textjoin) function then click on the [textjoin](/questions/tagged/textjoin) tag for suggestions on alternatives.

[image]

Comment: Nice Jeeped! I'm still living in the past, haven't caught up with `TEXTJOIN` yet...:)

Comment: Thanks dude, it should work I'll update my soft and give you my feedback

Comment: Thanks @Helloworld; I was concerned that you may have only wanted the first two matches regardless of whether there were three or more but that could be attained by concatenating your original formula with the 'second match' variation of Barry's formula below.

Comment: Well perfect, it worked, I've a question tho : Is it possible to have a comma betweet both names?

Comment: If you just want a comma, change `CHAR(32)` to `CHAR(44)`. If you want a comma and a space then use `CHAR(44)&CHAR(32)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this formula in K2

`=IFERROR(INDEX(D$3:D$14;SMALL(IF(H$3:H$14=MAX(H$3:H$14);ROW(H$3:H$14)-ROW(H$3)+1);ROWS(K$2:K2)));"")`

confirm with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> and copy down

This will give you all matches in successive cells

Comment: It doesn't work, it gives me only one name, for example it gives me "John" but "Alison" also have 20 so it should give me "John Alison" but it doesn't

Comment: My suggestion will only give you one name per cell, so if you put that formula in K2 and drag to K3 then it will give you "John" in K2 and "Alison" in K3. If there are more than 2 matches possible then you can drag further to get all of them. Once matches are exhausted you get blanks

Comment: To get all results in one cell is more difficult to do with formulas. What is the maximum number of matches?